# Animate imageButton resize to fit screen

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'd like to have an imagebutton center screen that open starting 'grows' to fill the entire screen smoothly using some sort of animation. upon reaching full size, reverse the animation and go back to its original size?

any ideas? is this even possible?

Comment: Definitely possible, have you tried to set up an animation xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample to get you started create an xml file for your animation using this layout, 
  res/anim/animate.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:shareInterpolator="false">
   <scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:duration="700" />
    </set>
```

and in your method to start the animation use this

```
 Animation scaleAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animate);
view.startAnimation( scaleAnim );
```

Learn more about animations here [Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: PERFECT! thank you very much, i have a new found love for animations!

Comment: And any ideas about how to animate a view to fit the screen?